I have a problem in my multi-level nav menu css is there anyone can help me?
My sub menu showing in same row with its parent i want to display it from top mean no gap from the top for each submenu ul.
It is right now working good just the gap need to remove from the to like screen shoots.
enter image description here
It will need to be same like https://thephonelab.nl/ when you hove any li you can see there are not top padding or margin here. I need the same look
My html is


.header .nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 80px;
}

/* Ensure only the immediate child submenu is shown */
.header .nav ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Submenu hidden by default */
.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 230px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(10, 10, 10, .1);
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff8c;
}


.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

/* Submenu within submenu - hidden by default */
.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    -ms-transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px));
    transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px));
    top: -5px;
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #f5f5f7;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(10, 10, 10, .1);
}

/* Show only the hovered submenu's child submenu */
.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    -ms-transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
    transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu a {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #353439;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #e72329;
}


.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Adjusted for cross-browser consistency */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Vertically centers the icon */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    right: 10px; /* Instead of margin-left, use right for better positioning */
    background-size: cover; /* Changed from contain to cover */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Ensure the icon doesn't repeat */
}
<div class="nav">
                    <div class="new_menu_class"><ul id="menu-header" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-544" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-544"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/">Repairs</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-556"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/">iPhone Reparatie</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-932"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-16">iPhone 16 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-803" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-803"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-804"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-802" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-802"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-805" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-805"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-reparatie/">iPhone 16</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-933"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-15">iPhone 15 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-799"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-800"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-798"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-801" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-801"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-reparatie/">iPhone 15</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-934" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-934"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-14">iPhone 14 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-795"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-796"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-794"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-797"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-reparatie/">iPhone 14</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-935" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-935"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-13">iPhone 13 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-791" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-791"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-792"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-790" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-790"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-mini-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Mini</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-793"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-reparatie/">iPhone 13</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-943" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-943"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-12">iPhone 12 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-945" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-945"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-946"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-944" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-944"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-mini-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Mini</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-947" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-947"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-reparatie/">iPhone 12</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-937" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-937"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-11">iPhone 11 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-948" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-948"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 11 Pro Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-949" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-949"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 11 Pro</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-950" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-950"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-reparatie/">iPhone 11</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-951" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-951"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-x">iPhone X Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-817"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xs-max-reparatie/">iPhone XS Max</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-952" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-952"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xs-reparatie/">iPhone XS</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-816"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xr-reparatie/">iPhone XR</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-815"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-x-reparatie/">iPhone X</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-953" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-953"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-8">iPhone 8 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-956" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-956"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-8-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-957" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-957"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-8-reparaties/">iPhone 8</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1006"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-7">iPhone 7 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-954" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-954"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-7-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-955" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-955"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-7-reparaties/">iPhone 7</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-958" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-958"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-7">iPhone 6 Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-959" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-959"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 6 Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-960" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-960"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6-reparaties/">IPhone 6</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-961" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-961"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6s-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 6S Plus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-962" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-962"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6s-reparaties/">IPhone 6S</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1007"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-se">iPhone SE Series</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1043"><a href="#">iPhone SE 2022</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-963" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-963"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-se-2020-reparatie/">iPhone SE 2020</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1042"><a href="#">iPhone SE 2016</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-964" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-964"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/samsung">Samsung Reparatie</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-968" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-968"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S24 Ultra</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-966" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-966"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S24 Plus</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-967" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-967"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-reparatie/">Galaxy S24</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-979" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-979"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S23 Ultra</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-977"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S23 Plus</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-978" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-978"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-reparatie/">Galaxy S23</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-976" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-976"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S22 Ultra</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-974" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-974"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S22 Plus</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-975" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-975"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-reparatie/">Galaxy S22</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-970" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-970"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-fe-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 FE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-973"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 Ultra</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-971"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 Plus</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-972" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-972"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-reparatie/">Galaxy S21</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-985" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-985"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 Ultra</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-982" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-982"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-fe-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 FE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-983" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-983"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 Plus</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-984" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-984"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-reparatie/">Galaxy S20</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-571" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-571"><a href="#">Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-570" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-570"><a href="#">OnePlus</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-568" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-568"><a href="#">Google</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-569"><a href="#">Macbook</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-541"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-581" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-581"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/tracking/">Tracking Your Booking</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-540" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-540"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-988"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div> 
            </div>




What the chance you can create a working example of your code (with tools such as https://jsbin.com, codesandbox or similar). Obviously it shouldn't be connected to your website or something, just html and css

The sub-sub menus are position: absolute so their parent need to be relative and it should be the top menu so that top: 0 would be the correct place. So I removed the relative from all the intermediate parents.
This made some issues with the caret for items having sub-menus. But I fixed that by not using position: relative for the li. Further tweaking might be needed.


.header .new_menu_class .menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav ul li {
  line-height: 80px;
  display: block;
}


/* Ensure only the immediate child submenu is shown */

.header .nav ul li:hover>ul.sub-menu {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Submenu hidden by default */

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 230px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 99999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(10, 10, 10, .1);
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children {
  //  position: relative;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff8c;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  //position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}


/* Submenu within submenu - hidden by default */

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu {
  -ms-transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px));
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px));
  top: -5px;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #f5f5f7;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(10, 10, 10, .1);
}


/* Show only the hovered submenu's child submenu */

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover>ul.sub-menu {
  -ms-transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #353439;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #e72329;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children>a {
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children>a::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHdpZHRoPSI1MTIiIGhlaWdodD0iNTEyIiB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEyIDUxMiIgc3R5bGU9ImVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kOm5ldyAwIDAgNTEyIDUxMiIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSIgY2xhc3M9IiI+PGc+PHBhdGggZD0iTTM4NS4xIDIxOS45IDE5OS4yIDM0Yy0yMC0yMC01Mi4zLTIwLTcyLjMgMHMtMjAgNTIuMyAwIDcyLjNMMjc2LjcgMjU2IDEyNi45IDQwNS43Yy0yMCAyMC0yMCA1Mi4zIDAgNzIuM3M1Mi4zIDIwIDcyLjMgMGwxODUuOS0xODUuOWMxOS45LTE5LjkgMTkuOS01Mi4zIDAtNzIuMnoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiIG9wYWNpdHk9IjEiIGRhdGEtb3JpZ2luYWw9IiMwMDAwMDAiIGNsYXNzPSIiPjwvcGF0aD48L2c+PC9zdmc+');
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* Adjusted for cross-browser consistency */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Vertically centers the icon */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  /* Instead of margin-left, use right for better positioning */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Changed from contain to cover */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Ensure the icon doesn't repeat */
}
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="new_menu_class">
      <ul id="menu-header" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-544" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-544"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/">Repairs</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-556"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/">iPhone Reparatie</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-932"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-16">iPhone 16 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-803" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-803"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-804"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-802" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-802"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 16 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-805" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-805"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-16-reparatie/">iPhone 16</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-933"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-15">iPhone 15 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-799"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-800"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-798"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 15 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-801" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-801"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-15-reparatie/">iPhone 15</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-934" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-934"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-14">iPhone 14 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-795"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-796"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-794"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 14 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-797"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-14-reparatie/">iPhone 14</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-935" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-935"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-13">iPhone 13 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-791" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-791"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-792"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-790" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-790"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-mini-reparatie/">iPhone 13 Mini</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-793"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-13-reparatie/">iPhone 13</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-943" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-943"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-12">iPhone 12 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-945" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-945"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-946" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-946"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-944" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-944"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-mini-reparatie/">iPhone 12 Mini</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-947" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-947"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-12-reparatie/">iPhone 12</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-937" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-937"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-11">iPhone 11 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-948" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-948"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-pro-max-reparatie/">iPhone 11 Pro Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-949" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-949"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-pro-reparatie/">iPhone 11 Pro</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-950" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-950"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-11-reparatie/">iPhone 11</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-951" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-951"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-x">iPhone X Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-817"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xs-max-reparatie/">iPhone XS Max</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-952" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-952"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xs-reparatie/">iPhone XS</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-816"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-xr-reparatie/">iPhone XR</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-815"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-x-reparatie/">iPhone X</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-953" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-953"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-8">iPhone 8 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-956" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-956"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-8-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-957" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-957"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-8-reparaties/">iPhone 8</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1006"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-7">iPhone 7 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-954" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-954"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-7-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-955" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-955"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-7-reparaties/">iPhone 7</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-958" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-958"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-7">iPhone 6 Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-959" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-959"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6-plus-reparatie/">iPhone 6 Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-960" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-960"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6-reparaties/">IPhone 6</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-961" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-961"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6s-plus-reparaties/">iPhone 6S Plus</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-962" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-962"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-6s-reparaties/">IPhone 6S</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1007"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/iphone/?series=iphone-se">iPhone SE Series</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1043"><a href="#">iPhone SE 2022</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-963" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-963"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/iphone-se-2020-reparatie/">iPhone SE 2020</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1042"><a href="#">iPhone SE 2016</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-964" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-964"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/repairs/samsung">Samsung Reparatie</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-968" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-968"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S24 Ultra</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-966" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-966"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S24 Plus</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-967" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-967"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s24-reparatie/">Galaxy S24</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-979" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-979"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S23 Ultra</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-977"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S23 Plus</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-978" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-978"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s23-reparatie/">Galaxy S23</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-976" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-976"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S22 Ultra</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-974" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-974"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S22 Plus</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-975" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-975"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s22-reparatie/">Galaxy S22</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-970" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-970"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-fe-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 FE</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-973"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 Ultra</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-971"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S21 Plus</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-972" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-972"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s21-reparatie/">Galaxy S21</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-985" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-985"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 Ultra</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-982" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-982"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-fe-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 FE</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-983" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-983"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-plus-reparatie/">Galaxy S20 Plus</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-984" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-models menu-item-984"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/samsung-galaxy-s20-reparatie/">Galaxy S20</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-571" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-571"><a href="#">Xiaomi</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-570" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-570"><a href="#">OnePlus</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-568" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-568"><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-569" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-569"><a href="#">Macbook</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-541"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/pricing/">Pricing</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-581" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-581"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/tracking/">Tracking Your Booking</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-540" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-540"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-988"><a href="https://ferry2.simpelfix.ch/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you so much, it is working ,I am very happy :)
